# how to add fields in inherited notebook/page/field

Tags: xpath, openerp-8, odoo-9

I have inherited 'sales order' from 'sales' module.

I need to add two extra fields inside 'Order Lines' tab.

.py

```
class SalesOrderInherit(models.Model):
        _inherit = "sale.order"
type = fields.Selection([('appointment', 'Appointment'), ('walkin', 'Walk-In')], string="Type")
```

I need to add type field inside 'Order Lines' tab.

Which table should i inherit?

How to write  to add above field.

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution

```
<record id="inherit_sale_order_line" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">inherit.sale.order.line.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="priority" eval="50" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[2]" position="after">
                <field name="type"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```